# How to show the following classes and their associations in UML?

Tags: java, uml

Let's pretend that I have two classes:

```
public class User {
 private Phone defaultPhone;
 private List<Phone> allPhones; 
}

public class Phone {
}
```

How should I model `User` and `Phone` in a UML Class Diagram?

In particular:

- Is it necessary to create an association link between `User` and `Phone`?

  - If so, should I create two association links (one for `defaultPhone` and one for `allPhones`)?
  - If I show these associations in the diagram, should I also display the `defaultPhone` and `allPhones` attributes in the `User` class or would that be redundant?

Comment: why you need extra class field for `defaultPhone`, wouldn't it be simplier if it would become first object in your `allPhones` list? You would have `1..*` Phones on your list.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what is the emphasis of your diagram. If the relation between user and phone is important and also you want to show some details about the phone class, then yes, you have to show the association between those classes. Otherwise you can show defaultPhone and allPhones as attributes of User class.
If you are drawing associations, then you will have to associations, one for each attribute. The associations role and multiplicity will differ from each other.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Answers that I currently see above are very descriptive and sufficient. Thus, from my side I can only add that you might consider (doesn't mean it's best in this specific case) using composite associations between those two classes since User is a container for Phone objects (at least from implementation perspective). If these are persistent objects, and User removal cascades on Phones, then I would use a composite.

.. and for the UML class diagram reference I would suggest this article: [Introduction to UML 2 Class Diagrams](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/classDiagram.htm) which once I found very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it necessary to create an
>   association link between User and
>   Phone?

What's the purpose of a UML diagram?  Who's the audience?  It's necessary if that level of detail is required.  Only you can decide that.

If you intend to give it to a developer who will re-do all the typing you did to create the diagram, except this time you'll end up with actual working code, then the detail is necessary.

If your audience is business folks who need a sense of what you're doing, perhaps not.

> If so, should I create two association
>   links (one for defaultPhone and one
>   for allPhones)?

Yes, one would be an association link and the other a simple reference.

> If I show these associations in the
>   diagram, should I also display the
>   defaultPhone and allPhones attributes
>   in the User class or would that be
>   redundant?

If your diagram shows every attribute and every method in all its glory, then you should include both.

But if it's more than a few classes, I'd say that your diagram is in danger of becoming so detailed that it'll be worthless.